# App to receive notifications triggered by URL request

Tags: linux, iphone, android, notifications

I would like to have an app for iPhone and Android (it doesn't need to be the same one) that simply displays a notification when externally triggered.

More to the point, I would like a PC application to figure out when to notify me, and then access some sort of HTTP API which in turn prompts the phone to notify me.

```
PC app ----(HTTP)-----> App Server ----(notification framework)--> my device
```

Does such a thing exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current recommendation would be [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) which works both for Android and iOS, has a very simple API and also a IFTTT recipe.

Previously I have been using [Push4](http://www.appnotifications.com/) but it recently went from being a paid app to a subscription model.

Comment: Pushover looks great. It's double the price of Prowl though, but this might be worth it to have a cross-platform solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I didn't do such a good job at googling :(

I have so far found [PyProwl](http://www.prowlapp.com/) for iPhone and [NotifyMyAndroid](http://www.notifymyandroid.com/). I'll leave this here in case someone has better alternatives